# Proxy to a load balancer automatically add additional path

Tags: apache-2.4, proxypass

I'm running httpd 2.4.6 on Redhat 7.9. I'm trying to use ProxyPass work with Balancer. Here is my configuration.

*Balancer*

```
<Proxy balancer://mycluster>
    BalancerMember http://10.10.12.103:8080
    BalancerMember http://10.10.12.107:8080
</Proxy>
```

*VirtualHost*

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>

    ServerName      www.abcdef.com
    DocumentRoot "/app/httpd/html"

    <Location /heartbeat >
    </Location>

    <Location /up >
        ProxyPass balancer://mycluster/myapp1
        ProxyPassReverse balancer://mycluster/myapp1
    </Location>
    <Location /myapp1 >
        ProxyPass balancer://mycluster/myapp1
        ProxyPassReverse balancer://mycluster/myapp1
    </Location>
    <Location / >
        ProxyPass balancer://mycluster/myapp1
        ProxyPassReverse balancer://mycluster/myapp1
    </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

I was hoping all 3 paths: /, /myapp1, /up can be all passed to /myapp1 on my backend servers. But I got 404 error for /myapp1 and /up.

I checked tomcat access log ad found something was added to the end of the url:

```
[03/May/2021:22:02:45 +0000]|10.10.55.55|10.29.9.6||-|http-bio-8076-exec-4|0|10.10.55.55|-|-|"-"|"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:32.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/32.0"|"GET /myapp1myapp1/ HTTP/1.1"|404|-
[03/May/2021:22:03:01 +0000]|10.10.55.55|10.29.9.6||-|http-bio-8076-exec-5|0|10.10.55.55|-|-|"-"|"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:32.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/32.0"|"GET /myapp1up/ HTTP/1.1"|404|-
```

The url changed: /up to /myapp1up/, /myapp1 to /myapp1myapp1/, obviously not exist.

I tried to research online and didn't find any result about this. Would someone have experience like this can shed some light why it has this kind of behavior? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem. It turns out it is because of the sequence of the  instruction. The shorter must be in first place like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>

    ServerName      www.abcdef.com
    DocumentRoot "/app/httpd/html"

    <Location /heartbeat >
    </Location>

    <Location / >
        ProxyPass balancer://mycluster/myapp1
        ProxyPassReverse balancer://mycluster/myapp1
    </Location>
    <Location /up >
        ProxyPass balancer://mycluster/myapp1
        ProxyPassReverse balancer://mycluster/myapp1
    </Location>
    <Location /myapp1 >
        ProxyPass balancer://mycluster/myapp1
        ProxyPassReverse balancer://mycluster/myapp1
    </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```